# The session is unavailable because no secret key was set

Tags: flask

I'm building a login form but I got stuck with sessions. When I try to login I get an error "The session is unavailable because no secret key was set". Please, check my code:

****init**.py** (the main file)

```
from flask import Flask
...
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gfgfgghghgfhgfhgfhgfhfgghghghghghg'
Session(app)
```

**routes.py** (of users blueprint)

```
from flask import render_template, session, url_for, redirect, request, Blueprint
...
from mywebsite.users.forms import (LoginForm, RegisterForm)
from mywebsite import db, bcrypt, app

users = Blueprint('users', "__name__")

@users.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    loginForm = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.pop('user_id', None)
```

Maybe I should pass the secret key to the *users* blueprint? If so, how do I do that?

P.S. when I get rid off **flask_session** it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "..."  # wrong
app.secret_key = "My Secret key"  # right
```

[Flask Documentation for Session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions)

[SO Question: Demystify Flask app secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463939/demystify-flask-app-secret-key)

EDIT: I have just noticed you are using `Flask-Session`.

Just a note that flask itself has sessions and you don't necessarily need this extension if you just need any sessions.

See [Flask-Session is an extension for Flask that adds support for Server-side Session to your application.](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and explanation [Flask-Session extension vs default session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084646/flask-session-extension-vs-default-session).

Anyways to get `Flask-Session` running you are additionally required to give it `SESSION_TYPE` configuration (See [secret key not set in flask session, using the Flask-Session extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080872/secret-key-not-set-in-flask-session-using-the-flask-session-extension/26080974#26080974)).

```
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
```

Comment: thank you so much!! Now it works! I thought the default session type would be okay. But I don't know anything about session types so that's why I had issues with flask_session. Thank you once again. You're truly the best!